# How to insert custom node script to Nuxt app?

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

I need to add a custom nodejs script to the project that performs a few manipulations on icon files before build and before starting development.

What is a good place to add it?
Maybe in nuxt.config.js or in some other place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `nuxt.config.js`

```
{
  ...,
  hooks: {
    build: {
      before(nuxt, buildOptions) {
        // your logic here
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

More about nuxt hooks: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-hooks/

More builder hooks: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/internals-builder/#hooks